# In unobtrusive JavaScript, once you've separated content and scripts, what do you do for a script that adds content?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm trying to follow best practices for unobtrusive JavaScript in my Rails 3 application. I've separated the HTML content and JavaScripts on my site for the most part. However, I have a form, where on the click of a script, it used to add additional HTML form elements. What's the best practice for this situation?

Since it's a form, I can't just pre-render and hide the element with the script causing it to show, because hidden form elements are still submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the new content programmatically (by creating nodes etc), or you can use a templating system to map data into pre-coded HTML templates.

When you hide portions of a form, you can find all the inputs and disable them (set the "disabled" attribute to `true`) to prevent them from being submitted.

To be "unobtrusive", if you go with a templating system you need to have the templates organized somehow. Some people like coding them into the page, sometimes as raw uninterpreted text by sneaking them into a `<script>` tag with a type that keeps the browser from trying to interpret it:

```
<script type='text/template' id='templateName'>
  <div class='part-of-a-template'>
    <!-- etc etc -->
  </div>
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can serve up the templates embedded into JavaScript or JSON data, possibly by server-side facilities that respond to dynamic requests for templates. How you do it depends on what your needs are.